# What kind of interacion is there between a nanoparticle and its functionalizing coating?

Tags: bond, nanotechnology

The [functionalization of nanoparticles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanoparticle#Functionalization) (with coatings such as polymer ligands; see [image](http://what-when-how.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/tmp64293_thumb.jpg)) are very common (for example, DNA-functionalizied gold nanoparticles). What's the type of interaction between nanoparticles and their coatings? And why is it more favorable than forming aggregations of the the nanoparticles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In small nanoclusters/nanocrystals/quantum clusters (my goodness, they have so many names nowadays) in the size range around 13, 55 and 144 metal atoms,<sup>1</sup> the ligands enter a real orbital interaction ([dative bond](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/atoms/bonding/dative.html)<sup>2</sup>). They are ligated to the metal core ([Puls et. al., 2014](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/anie.201310436)).

In DNA-ligated gold clusters, the phosphate groups are able to bond to the metal core and substitute the phosphine ligands it had before ([Yunping et. al., 2003](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/anie.200250235)).

In larger nanoparticles,<sup>3</sup> the tendency of the particles to agglomerate is much smaller. Some of them can be measured with TEM (Transmission Electron Microscopy) without full agglomeration. This is not given for the small 13 metal atom clusters. The big particles enter interactions with their surfactants for which the main contribution is given either by van der Waals forces, or by electrostatic interactions.

---

<sup>1</sup> Those are some of the most common numbers in gold cluster chemistry, like $\text{Au}_{13}(\text{PR}_3)_{12}$ for example. 55 and 144 can be found in thiolated gold clusters.

<sup>2</sup> It has covalent portions as well as ionic. It is, however, better understood if you think of coordination complexes. Only in this case, there is not only a single metal atom in the centre

<sup>3</sup> i.e. 5 nm, 12 nm. I stated this because I am not aware of any case in which a 13-metal-atom cluster was analysed by TEM (Transmission Electron Microscopy). The conditions are simply too harsh, the ligand shell is ripped off and the little clusters experience a very strong tendency to agglomerate. You need specialised TEM equipment to acquire meaningful data. Nanoparticles of a few nanometers are less prone to show such a fast agglomeration.

Comment: where do the numbers 13,55,144 come from?

Comment: Those are some of the most common numbers in gold cluster chemistry, like $\ce{Au13(PR3)12}$ for example. 55 and 144 can be found in thiolated gold clusters.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "enter orbital interaction"? covalent bond?

Comment: In this case I mean a dative bond. http://www.chemguide.co.uk/atoms/bonding/dative.html It has covalent portions as well as ionic. It is, however, better understood if you think of coordination complexes. Only in this case, there is not only a single metal atom in the centre.

Comment: you said larger nanoparticles agglomerate less. by "larger" you mean larger than 13 metal atoms?

Comment: In this case I meant 5 nm, 12 nm. I stated this because I am not aware of any case in which a 13-metal-atom cluster was analysed by TEM (Transmission Electron Microscopy). The conditions are simply too harsh, the ligand shell is ripped off and the little clusters experience a very strong tendency to agglomerate. You need specialised TEM equipment to acquire meaningful data. Nanoparticles of a few nanometers are less prone to show such a fast agglomeration.

Comment: Sorry, I just removed the "superatom model" part. I confused that with a different consideration. Therein, the AuL units are viewed as ligands to the central atom in $\ce{[M(AuPMe3)11(AuCl)][GaCl4]3}$ with (M = Ni, Pd, Pt). The twelve AuL "ligands" then form molecular orbitals which are reminiscent of atomic orbitals and thus can be described with the superatom model. (http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/anie.201310436)